# IIS Log Report With SOLR

Tags: solr

I wanna Use SOLR to get report from IIS's Log and i have some Questions

1- Is it SOLR a solution for this scenario??

2- If yes is there any standard schema for that ? ( base on W3C logging Schema)

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a Logstash-Elasticsearch-Kibana combo might be better suited for this.

Comment: Elasticsearch was too slow for my searching and dashboard reporting i change it to solr by the way thank you :)